# nginx and php-fpm permission

Tags: nginx, permissions, php-fpm

I have a problem with nginx / php-fpm permissions.

I run a website in /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web, the owner:group of that folder and subfolders is web1:client1. When I try to create or upload a file with a PHP script in that folder i get a Permission Denied error because the new file get's created as www-data:www-data and it can't write to the folder (I have tested this by using the 777 permission).

How can I make it so nginx / php-fpm can write to those folders using web1:client1 and not www-data:www-data?

php-fpm pool file for that site:

```
[web1]

listen = /var/lib/php5-fpm/web1.sock  
listen.owner = web1  
listen.group = client1 
listen.mode = 0660

user = web1 
group = client1

pm = dynamic pm.max_children = 10 
pm.start_servers = 2 
pm.min_spare_servers = 1 
pm.max_spare_servers = 5 
pm.max_requests = 0

chdir = /

php_admin_value[open_basedir] = /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web:/var/www/clients/client1/web1/private:/var/www/clients/client1/web1/tmp:/usr/share/php5:/usr/share/php:/tmp:/usr/share/phpmyadmin:/etc/phpmyadmin:/var/lib/phpmyadmin 
php_admin_value[session.save_path] = /var/www/clients/client1/web1/tmp
php_admin_value[upload_tmp_dir] = /var/www/clients/client1/web1/tmp
```

Comment: Have you tried searching?  I don't use php-fpm and the first search I tried on google has quite a few number of links that answer your question.

Comment: I did and they suggest having the user/group in php-fpm same as the user/group on the folder, witch I have.

Comment: If you already have it done, then what's your question?

Comment: As I said in the question, I have done it, but the new files get created under www-data:www-data and not web1:client1 as set in the config file.

Comment: What does your nginx configuration look like?  If you have it configured correctly where it is running as your defined user, it would be writing files as that user.

Comment: what matters is the `user` directive in your nginx.conf - which you haven't shown but is clearly not `user web1 client1;`.

Comment: Did you restart `php5-fpm` after making the username changes? What does `ps aux` show for the php-fpm processes?

Comment: nginx `user` directive doesn't matter with PHP scripts executed via PHP-FPM.

Comment: ps aux shows process under the web1,web2,web3 users and www-data like web1      7743  0.0  0.2 487352  4452 ?        S    Oct31   0:00 php-fpm: pool web1